# Pyrebase how can access multiple keys systematically and print their child data?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I’m planning to how the real time database store data for a quiz like this:

[example of how database looks here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t8En.jpg)

How can i go through each key to print out the child data stored underneath each one systematically?

edit:
this is how i am storing the data in the real time database
`db.child(uidToken).child("titleDate").set(data)`
and this is some example data thats being stored
`data = { "score": "3/5", "date": "20/8/20", "title": "quizTitle" }`

'uidToken' is the user ID

Comment: can you show some code? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data this migt help or if  you want to get data in real time https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#python_1

Comment: @user13966865 I suspect OP is using the Realtime Database, but your question is equally valid there. stackuser7: the Pyrebase documentation shows how to read and loop through keys: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#retrieve-data. Without seeing what you've tried and where you got stuck, it is unlikely we'll do a better job explaining it than that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i adding in the post how im storing the data but i already deleted my previous attempt to get the data. and yes im using a real time database. I'll try again with the links you sent but im still not sure how i would systematically get the data from each randomly generated key

Comment: @user13966865 ^^^

Comment: The `each` section in the docs shows how to do that: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#each. If you can't get that to work, show the code of what you tried. Without seeing that, it is unlikely we can help better than that documentation.